# Squash a new commit in a merge request

Tags: git

I have committed and pushed a file to create a Merge Request. Now I have been requested to apply some changes to the file and squash commits in the Merge request.
My common practice, to squash commits, when all changes are committed is:

```
git checkout my_branch
git reset --soft HEAD~4
git commit
git push --force origin my_branch
```

In this case, however, I have not yet committed or pushed the new changes. Is there a simpler way (other than a git reset) to include new commits in the existing one that has been already pushed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have your changes ready, if you want to squash them into the previous commit you can do

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

This will add those changes into the previous commit, and keep the same commit message.